# Custom loading .NET AppDomains inside a process - what's the addressable memory for each appdomain?

Tags: .net, memory, appdomain

I have a process that uses AppDomain.CreateDomain() to spin up and then down new application domains inside my worker process.

What is the maximum addressable memory for each of the AppDomains on a 32-bit OS?  Is it 2gb or do all of the AppDomains share the 2gb limit of the host process?

Comment: they share. process space is defined on windows process level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one GC heap, all AppDomains allocate from it.  So there's no fixed maximum size for each, the sum of all allocations can never exceed the address space limit.